# C# getting next day entered by user

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am creating my own date class which should get the next day inputted by the user e.g. if a user types in `18/03/1920` for example then this should return the next day. The format currently is `dd/MM/yyyy`. I was just wondering how would I come across solving this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace date
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("please enter date as dd/MM/yy");
            Console.ReadLine();
            date i = new date(01, 12, 1920);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}", i.day, i.month, i.year);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        class date
        {
            public int month; // 1-12
            public int day; // 1-31 depending on month
            private int value;
            public int year
            {
                get;
                private set;
            }
            public date(int day, int month, int year)
            {
                this.day = day;
                this.month = month;
                this.year = year;
                Console.WriteLine("Date object constructor for date {0}");
            }

            public int getYear()
            {
                return year;
            }

            public void setYear()
            {
                if (value > 1900 && value <= 2020)
                    year = value;
                else
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("year", value, "out of bounds");
            }

            public int getMonth()
            {
                return month;
            }

            public void setMonth()
            {
                if (value > 0 && value <= 12)
                    month = value;
                else
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Month", value, "Month must be 1-12");
            }

            public int getDay()
            {
                return day;
            }

            public void setDay()
            {
                int[] days = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

                if (value > 0 && value <= days[month])
                    day = value;

                else if (month == 2 && value == 29 &&
                    year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0))
                    day = value;
                else
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Day", value, "day is out of range");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask *why* you're creating your own date class? (As an aside, you should really follow .NET naming conventions, and learn about properties - your code looks very much like Java at the moment...) (I see you've already got `year` as a property - so why have `getYear` and `setYear` at all?) Also note that your `setDay` method is missing a `value` parameter... you've got a value field, but you're never setting it to anything.

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to experiment with creating my own and not using the preset DateTime. Just wanted a challenge

Comment: I have some suspicions that you are a Java developer :) In order to not confuse any other developers, please follow C# naming conventions. Method and class names should start from a capital letter.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev sorry I used to do a lot of java and sometimes get really confused

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are confusing properties and methods.

Here `value` is an unknown variable. It will result into `Cannot resolve symbol` error. I am sure that it is the same as in Java - you definitely cannot use nonexistent variables :)

```
public void setMonth()
{
    if (value > 0 && value <= 12)
        month = value; // <-- value is unknown
    else
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Month", value, "Month must be 1-12");
}
```

At the same time, in C# we have properties. They allow you to conveniently encapsulate accessing \ setting logics:

```
public int Month 
{ 
    get { return month; }
    set 
    {
        if (value > 0 && value <= 12)
            month = value; // <-- here, value does exist
        else
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Month", value, "Month must be 1-12");    
    }
}
```

Then, you will be able to use it:

```
var dt = new date(1, 1, 1);
dt.Month = 5; // property setter
Console.WriteLine(dt.Month); // property getter
dt.Month = 17; // <-- throws exception
```

Just convert your `setSomething`, `getSomething` methods to properties and will see that it works.

Note that you shouldn't make variables public if they have a property.

```
public int month; // shouldn't be public
private int Month 
{ 
    get { return month; }
    set 
    {
        if (value > 0 && value <= 12)
            month = value; // <-- here, value does exist
        else
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Month", value, "Month must be 1-12");    
    }
}
```

So, this property will become useless and you will be able do:

```
dt.Month = 17; // property setter throws exception
dt.month = 17; // simply sets field value
```

You need to hide this variable.

Also, as I mentionted in comments, in order to not confuse any other developers, please follow C# naming conventions. Method and class names should start from a capital letter.